# How to install sun-gridengine in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Following [this site](http://webappl.blogspot.com/2011/05/install-sun-grid-engine-sge-on-ubuntu.html), I'm trying to install the `gridengine` in `ubuntu 14.04`, but there is no `/var/lib/gridengine/mpi/startmpi.sh` existing.
Is it right that the structure of directories have been changed in `ubuntu 14.04`?

Once before, I've installed the `gridengine` sucessfully. How could I install it in `ubuntu 14.04`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to find it in installed packages:

```
dpkg -S startmpi.sh
```

I think that it has been moved to examples: /usr/share/doc/gridengine-common/examples/mpi/startmpi.sh

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm trying to install it following [http://keksec.bplaced.net/2014/06/grid-engine-cluster-ubuntu-14-04/].